# spectral mask and power spectral density

Tags: digital-communications

I have been reading a paper that specifies the spectral mask for certain communication devices attempting transmit over a channel

[image]

Can someone explain

1) importance if this spectral mask, is it a filter ?

2) what do we mean by roll off at the pass band from -28 dBr to -20 dBr.

3) Also why is the unit of measurement dBr and not db

Thank you very much

Comment: Spectral mask is used for a definition of the standardised bandwidth in order to minimize the interference. It is not a filter per se, it's simply a requirement for the particular standard. I.e. here is some [**example**](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ypcRS5ATyps/T5Me6-Xg1lI/AAAAAAAAAOY/qnQ5CO06ywE/s1600/transmit+mask+IEEE+802.11-2007+Fig+I.1.png) of the mask for a wi-fi. Spectral roll-off is what it is, as it defines how steep is the curve. dBr is a definition used for any unit with respect to a reference level. I.e. for sound pressure dBr is with reference to 20uPa.

Comment: Thank you very much for clear explanation, if it is not a filter, then how can  devices such as wifi devices make sure they meet this requirement? i.e what do they use to meet this spectral mask? @jojek

Comment: Like I said, it is not a filter - it's a requirement and every device must comply to that. Whether you use filters, design you device in a specific way - it's up to you. You must be sure that it is met. One analogy is a filter mask used when designing any type of an A-weighted auditory filter. No one cares how you do it - it must be within the boundaries.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you like to write this an asnwer so I can accept it.?